# How to intercept whole assembly using Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container, postsharp

In my current project i have implemented Exception Aspect using PostSharp. And PostSharp support applying this aspect for entire assembly, so i no need to specify the Exception attribute to each and every method.

But when it comes to Unity 2:
I have seen one sample in Unity 2 for Exception handling using method interception, but it is working only if i register the Type in Unity Container & resolve it.

It's fine for me to resolve the Type before using it, but in **Unity**, is there anyway to register all types & methodes in single shot?

In short, using Unity 2, i'm looking to intercept all methods in an assmebly just like we do in PostSharp

Comment: in postsharp or unity? You only need 1 declaration when using postsharp, you don't have to do it on each method. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Why not PostSharp? You're going to get better results.

Comment: @DustinDavis - out of license cost, i can not go with PostSharp

Comment: Unity can't do it out of the box and I don't think there is an easy workaround to implement it.

Comment: @Veeru you can create a LocationInterceptionAspect with PostSharp starter edition. No license cost. The cost of the license is well worth the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write some reflection to iterate through all the types in your assembly and register them all in Unity. This isn't too much of a hardship - should be just a simple call to Assembly.GetTypes()  to retrieve all types and then iterate over them, registering each one into Unity with the appropriate interceptor.

If you use full-blown Interceptors rather than Policies they will by default act over all method calls on any type that they are registered with.